# Los datos de mi petición no llegan a mi controlador

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, .net-5

Tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo un modelo en .NET 5 el cual es el siguiente

```
public class CreateMedicalHistory
{
    public int IdClient { get; set; }
    public MedicalHistory MedicalHistory { get; set; }
    public VisualAcuity VisualAcuity { get; set; }
    public EyeLeft EyeLeft { get; set; }
    public EyeRight EyeRight { get; set; }
}

public class MedicalHistory
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}
public class VisualAcuity
{
    public string SC { get; set; }
    public string PH { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string AVFinal { get; set; }
}
public class EyeLeft
{
    public string SPH { get; set; }
    public string CYL { get; set; }
    public string EJE { get; set; }
    public string ADD { get; set; }
}
public class EyeRight
{
    public string SPH { get; set; }
    public string CYL { get; set; }
    public string EJE { get; set; }
    public string ADD { get; set; }
}
```

Con AJAX intento enviar un con JSON.stringify(model)

```
{"IdClient":4,"MedicalHistory":{"DateTime":"02/02/2023 06:29:11 p. m.","Place":"Prueba"},"VisualAcuity":{"SC":"Prueba","PH":"Prueba","CC":"Prueba","AVFinal":"Prueba"},"EyeLeft":{"SPH":"1","CYL":"2","EJE":"3","ADD":"4"},"EyeRight":{"SPH":"1","CYL":"2","EJE":"3","ADD":"4"}}
```

en la siguiente petición

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Clients/CreateMedicalHistory",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        swal("The record was added successfully.!", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Pero al llegar al controlador me dice que el model esta null
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté varias formas, pero siempre llega null.

Les agradezco de ante mano.

Saludos.

Comment: en un post, put, los datos no tienen que ir en la propiead body? no en data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma predetermina asp.net va a buscar los datos como si fueran campos de formulario, a menos que tu aplicación sea del tipo "API" o el controlador tenga el atributo `[ApiController]`, para los casos contrarios se debe indicar la fuente de la solicitud, en tu caso desde el Body

Ejemplo

```
public IActionResult CreateMedicalHistory([FromBody]CreateMedicalHistory modelMedical)
```

Más información en [Documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! no sabía eso, te lo agradezco.