# No encuentro el metodo en mi API desde un cliente C# .NET

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc

tengo un problema, tengo una API en el cual tengo el siguiente metodo

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("insert")]
 public ResponseOutputModel<UsuarioPerfilOperacionCreateInputModel> Insert(string inputModel)
 {    
     try
     {
         //hacer algo
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {             
     }     
 }
```

Estoy intentando acceder al metodo "Insert" desde un cliente con el siguiente metodo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(string inputModel)
try
    {
        WscRequest<ResponseOutputModel<UsuarioPerfilOperacionCreateInputModel>> request = wsm3.Post<ResponseOutputModel<UsuarioPerfilOperacionCreateInputModel>>("/insert", inputModel);

        if (!request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return Json(new AjaxResponseOutputModel() { Success = false, Message = "No se pudo procesar la solicitud desde el sitio hacia el servidor de Api inténtelo nuevamente." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        if (!request.Data.Success)
            return Json(new AjaxResponseOutputModel() { Success = false, Message = request.Data.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            
        return Json(new AjaxResponseOutputModel() { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogManager.Add(ex);
        return Json(new AjaxResponseOutputModel() { Success = false, Message = "Error interno en el servidor, inténtelo nuevamente. Consulte Log" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

El parametro "inputModel" contiene un arreglo Json que se crea en la vista del sistema cliente, tal como se muestra a continuacion:

```
[{"IdModulo":2,"IdPerfil":2,"IdOperacion":4},{"IdModulo":2,"IdPerfil":2,"IdOperacion":5}]
```

El problema es que no esta adjuntando el parametro "inputModel" en la llamada a "insert", esto lo compruebo cuando omito en el metodo de mi API el parametro "string inputModel", con éste simple cambio ya alcanzo ese metodo. Espero alguien me pudiera orientar, se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/581415/301324